# How do I retrieve data from a hidden column in GridView? VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm kind of stuck here, after doing some research I can't seem to find an answer. Anyway I don't know how can I retrieve the Primary key in my Gridview hidden column.

Here is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="852px" DataKeyNames="app_id">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApp" runat="server" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApp" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_id" HeaderText="app_id" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_rsn" HeaderText="Reason" SortExpression="Reason" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_info" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_sts" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient" HeaderText="Requested by" SortExpression="Patient" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="app_timestamp" HeaderText="Date requested" SortExpression="Date requested" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my code at button click

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In grdDent.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim chkApp As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("chkApp"), CheckBox)
            If chkApp.Checked Then
                cmd = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE appointment_table SET app_sts = 'Approved' WHERE app_id = @p1", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", row.Cells(1).Text)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Here is my code to fill up the gridview

```
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT app_id, app_date, app_time, app_rsn, app_info, app_sts, group_concat(pat_lname, pat_fname) As Patient, app_timestamp FROM appointment_table INNER JOIN patient_table WHERE app_sts = 'Queue'", con)
            con.Open()
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            Dim a As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            a.Fill(ds)
            grdDent.DataSource = ds
            grdDent.DataBind()
            con.Close()
        End Using
```

The problem now is that whenever I click the button, it would not do anything, not even show an error, so I do not know what to do.

Comment: Did you debug? Did the code runt when button clicked? I mean does it satisfy the condition If chkApp.Checked ?

Comment: I did, and the code is not running when I click the button

Comment: Ok, is your GridView loaded with data before you click the button? I.e. check whether grdDent.Rows.Count > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In yourgrid.Rows
   Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkApp"), CheckBox)
   If chk IsNot Nothing And chk.Checked Then
      'get your selected row data here and perform update operation
End If
Next row
```

**NOTE:** My suggestion is to first debug the code and make sure your code is working fine and method is calling perfectly.

You can check [getting asp.net gridview selected row data from server-side](http://www.aspneto.com/get-asp-net-gridview-selected-row-data-code-behind-using-c-vb-net.html) to get more details.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Web 2013 and solution configuration is set on Debug. Tried the code still the same.

Comment: Are you sure you put break point before debug? Also update your question with your asp.net button and the whole code-behind code of click event, so i can be sure and check if there is any issue there.

Answer (score 0):

First debug the code and check from which line you are getting the error.

Also try following code.

    .HideData
    {
        display: none;
    }

Replace your app_id bound field like as below.

Don't use visible false property.

Answer (score 0):

when you set `visible=false` that column will not rendered in gridview's html.
so, instead of `visible=false` make its `style='display:none'`

use like this :

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDesc" HeaderText="app_id"  >
                 <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden"/>

                 </asp:BoundField>



<style type="text/css">
     .hidden
     {
         display:none;
     }
</style>
```

and use this in your `foreach` loop

```
dim appid as string

appid=row.Cells(1).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you store the primary key in DataKeyNames="app_id"
so you would grab that in code with

```
grdDent.DataKeys.Item(a row index here).Value
```

You can drop the BoundField holding this value. It being "Visible=False" will not hold any value.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is like this..

1st remove your boundfield and just add a lable to one of the template fields like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="852px" DataKeyNames="app_id">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApp" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApp" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblApp_ID" Visible="False" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("app_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app_date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app_time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app_rsn" HeaderText="Reason" SortExpression="Reason" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app_info" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app_sts" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient" HeaderText="Requested by" SortExpression="Patient" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app_timestamp" HeaderText="Date requested" SortExpression="Date requested" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

by doing this it will put the label in each row but it wont show up to the user and the part that says "`Text='<%# Bind("app_id") %>'`" that binds the text to that label in each row.

Now for the code on the button click you should use this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim app_ID As Integer '<- I was using an integer but you can use any datatype
    For Each row As GridViewRow In grdDent.Rows
        If CType(row.FindControl("chkApp"), CheckBox).Checked = True Then
            app_ID = CType(grdDent.Rows(i).FindControl("lblApp_ID"), Label).Text
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE appointment_table SET app_sts = 'Approved' WHERE app_id =" & app_ID , con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End If
        i += 1
    Next
```

All of this has worked for me, so I hope it works for you!